# How to create a list of clickable items using Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

In my Spring Boot web app, I need to create a list of items using Thymeleaf where clicking and submitting an item sends its value to my controller, which looks like this:

```
@PostMapping({"/mylist"})
public ModelAndView postList(@RequestParam(value = "item") String item) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("mylist");
    mav.addObject("items", someRepository.findAll());
    ...
    return mav;
}
```

Note the controller takes an `item` parameter.

For comparison, this following Thymeleaf *dropdown list* performs as expected in that when I select an item from the dropdown, then click Submit, the above controller receives that item's value:

```
<form th:action="@{/mylist}" method="post">
    ...
    <div>
        <select th:name="item">
            <option th:each="item : ${metaqueryitems}"
                    th:value="${item.code}"
                    th:selected="${item.id eq item}"
                    th:text="${item.id}"></option>
        </select>
        <td><input type="submit" th:value="Submit"/></td>
    </div>
    ...
</form>
```

But instead of a dropdown list, I want to show the items in a regular, *non-dropdown* list, such as the following:

```
<form th:action="@{/mylist}" method="post">
    ...
    <div th:name="item" th:each="item : ${items}">
        <input type="submit" th:value="${item.code}"/>
    </div>
    ...
</form>
```

However, when I click an item in the above list, the controller always ends up with a null value for the `item` parameter.

How do I send value from a th:each style Thymeleaf list over to my controller?

Comment: `<div>` elements don't typically have `name` attributes. But each of your `<input>` elements _does_ need a `name` attribute in order to be processed as part of the form submission.

Comment: Thanks, andrewJames. I added that (see above) and still for some reason get a null value in the controller on submit.

Comment: Wait - i take that back. I fixed my change and it works now!

Comment: Glad you resolved it. If you think it may help future visitors to this question you can provide your own answer. (Or, if you think  this question is a duplicate of an existing question, with the same answer, you can flag your question as a dupe.)

Comment: Will do! Or you can post an answer (which is just the th:each segment I show above, but with th:name="item" added to the input section and removed from the div part) and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `name="item"` to each `<input>` element:

```
<div th:each="item : ${metaqueryitems}">
    <input type="submit" name="item" th:value="${item.code}"/>
</div>
```

Note that because `item` is just a literal string there is no need to use `th:name=...` here. You can just use `name=...`.

---

Just a note of caution here: Within a form, you typically want to ensure that every input element has a unique `name` value, so you know which user-entered value came from which input element.

```html
<form action="..." method="post">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">
    <input type="text" name="lastname"  id="lastname">
</form>
```

In this very specific case, you can get away with them all using the same name (`item`) because you only ever submit one non-null value at a time.